# mvc- jquery - json encode attribute search

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I am working with MVC and JQuery and I have the following situation:
I have a dropdown list auto populated with ViewData["product"] (data is passed to this viewdata from database in the controller), I also have a textbox called price,
my goal is when the user select a product the price textbox should be filled with the corresponding product price, I have a viewdata["retailprice"], this is what I got so far

```
 $("#productname").change(function ()
                {
                    getprice();
                })
                function getprice()
                {
                    var productname = $("#productname").val();
                    var clienttype = $("#clienttype").val();


                    if (clienttype  == "Retail")
                    {
                        var x = {};
      for(x in JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["retailprice"]))'))
                        {
                            if(x == productname)
                            {
                                $("#productprice").val(x);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }
```

the value of the json encode looks something like this

```
[{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"1.75","Value":"1"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"2.50","Value":"2"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"4.90","Value":"3"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"4.70","Value":"4"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"8.70","Value":"6"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"50.00","Value":"10"}]
```

productname variable contain the value  property ex. "2"so basically I want to do something like this

```
if(x.value == productname)
                        {
                            $("#productprice").val(x.text);
                            break;
                        }
```

I know that not the right syntax but that's only for explanation.
FYI with the above code when I change the productname dropdown list the product price text box change value to 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 only and honestly I dont know from where these values are coming from

Comment: `x` is an object, so it would need to be `if (x.Value == productname) { $("#productprice").val(x.Text); ... }` (note javascript is case sensitive)

Comment: And as a side note, its just `for(x in @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["retailprice"])))` - its unnecessary extra overhead to convert the array to a string and then convert it back to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation of for.. in loop [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Change code to this:

```
const data = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["retailprice"]))');
for(x in data)
{
        if(data[x].Value == productname)
        {
                $("#productprice").val(data[x].Text);
                break;
        }
}
```